# System.Data.SQLite Can't Load Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

I'm trying to load the new json1 extension when the connection in set up, but I keep receiving this error:

> SQL logic error or missing database
>   The specified procedure could not be found.

Here is my code:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = (SQLiteConnection)session.Connection;
connection.EnableExtensions(true);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("System.Data.SQLite");
connection.LoadExtension(assembly.Location, "sqlite3_json_init");
```

I'm using NHibernate, so I just grab the connection from the session before any logic is executed.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I've also tried loading SQLite.Interop.dll and then calling the `sqlite3_json_init` method and that still does not work.

I did this and it still doesn't seem to work:

```
     SQLiteConnection connection = (SQLiteConnection)session.Connection;
                connection.EnableExtensions(true);
                string path = "F:\\GitHub\\ExampleProj\\lib\\sqlite\\SQLite.Interop.dll";
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    connection.LoadExtension(path,
"sqlite3_json_init");
                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually looks like you do not need to enter in the full path to the interop file.. apparently it identifies which processor architecture you are using and finds the SQLite.Interop.dll file in the bin folder based on that (bin/x64/SQLite.Interop.dll). I just had to give it the name of the interop file and it worked:

```
 SQLiteConnection connection = (SQLiteConnection)sender;
                connection.EnableExtensions(true);

                connection.LoadExtension("SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init");
```

Comment: This is what originally does not work. It can not find the module

Answer (score 6):

Loading the extension from SQLite.Interop.dll is the correct way. So you should just be able to do the following:

```
connection.EnableExtensions(true);
connection.LoadExtension(@"full\path\to\SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init");
```

I've tested this and it's working, so if you still have a problem, you may need to indicate how you're getting the path of the interop file. For debugging purposes, maybe add an assertion before LoadExtension to make sure the interop file that you're trying to load actually exists where you think it does.

Also make sure that you're loading the correct version (x86 vs. x64.) If you try the wrong one, you'll get, "The specified module could not be found." on the LoadExtension call even when it's actually there.

Comment: I just pass in the full path to the sqlite.interop file, I've editing the question above to show how I include the interop file

Comment: Right now I'm setting the build configuration to Any CPU, could that be the cause?

Comment: Possibly. There are two versions of the SQLite.Interop.dll, one for 32bit, one for 64bit. You have to load the correct one depending on how your application is running. Also make sure you're using System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.99.0 or greater (with matching interop library) as that was the first to support json1.

Comment: I'm running the version newer than 1.0.99.0 I've also tried both the 32bit and 64bit binaries. Nothing seems to be working, is there documentation on this? I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: this worked for me on a linux docker image. it wouldn't find the dll (and would try to add ".so" to the file name) when not provided the full path.